# Accessing a method which was assigned to a passed in Func<> parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic-dispatch

Looks like I've missed something obvious but really can't figure out why I can't use/access a method which was assigned to a passed in `Func<>` parameter, I want to access/call it in the external calling context.

Below the simple example: (real `results` data type is not `string` but some complex type)

```
class Caller
{
    private Func<string> factory;

    public Caller()
    {
        this.factory = null;
        var adapter = new Adapter(this.factory);
        adapter.Adapt(...);

        // then I would share this factory via IoC
        dependencyContainer.RegisterUsingFactoryMethod<string>(this.factory);

        // !!! but here is factory still not assigned
        string results = this.factory();
    }
}

class Adapter
{
    private string results;

    public Adapter(Func<string> factory)
    {
        factory = () => this.results;
    }

    public IOut Adapt(IIn input)
    {
       this.results = someCalculatedData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with delegates, and everything to do with the fact that all arguments are passed by value by default. You'd see the same behaviour if `factory` were an `int`, or a `string`, or a `StringBuilder`.

If you want your `Service` constructor to modify the value of the argument, you need a `ref` or `out` parameter. However, I would personally suggest that you change it to use a method which *returns* a `Func<string>`:

```
public class Caller
{
    private readonly Func<string> factory;

    public Caller()
    {
        this.factory = Service.GetFunc();
    }
}

public class Service
{
    public static Func<string> GetFunc()
    {
        return () => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

(There are various other options here, such as a method group conversion, or a property. It's hard to know what to recommend when we don't have much context.)

Obviously you'd want to rename the method. But calling a constructor solely to modify an `out` parameter would be a very odd bit of code.

For more on parameter passing, see my [article on the topic](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

Comment: +1 and thanks for providing different solutions with interesting concerns, really I know that simply can expose a method but this slightly messing up an API of a service. The idea that service on a specific stage (not construction as in example) able to initialize a factory so I can use it later, really I'm not sure perhaps overall design with this approach is wrong

Comment: @sll: But why do you *want* to construct a `Service` object? You should be interested in what that actually provides. Any time you call a constructor and completely ignore the newly-created object, you should be concerned.

Comment: Ok this is not a service but some kind of adapter, and whilst data transformation it should cache some intermediate data for future use, the isea was to register this data in the IoC container but this requires injecting IoC into the adapter and I do not like this idea, but now it looks like not much too bad than injecting `ref Func`

Comment: @sll: I'm afraid we still don't really have enough information to go on - we'd need to see a lot more of the big picture. But the use of a `ref` parameter in a constructor call where the returned object is then discarded is a *really* nasty code smell IMO.

Comment: sorry, I've added more details to the original question so it reflects a real case

Comment: @sll: Okay, in that case I'd use a method group conversion, probably: `this.factory = new Service().GetResults;` where `GetResults()` is a public method returning results - or even `var service = new Service(); this.factory = () => service.Results;` where it's a property. The fact that you want to use this as a delegate doesn't feel like something the service should care about.

Comment: Makes sense, I would stick with a results as property approach. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

Can you try pasing the func with an out parameter to the constructor of Service?

e.g.

```
class Caller
{
    private Func<string> factory;

    public Caller()
    {
        this.factory = null;
        var service = new Service(out this.factory);

        // !!! but here is factory still not assigned
        string results = this.factory();
    }
}

class Service
{
    public Service(out Func<string> factory)
    {
        factory = () => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

This will ensure the compiler knows to initialize the reference to factory parameter in the Service constructor. Otherwise you are just passing a reference to the null Func to the constructor by value then locally assigning the function to that variable on the stack inside the ctor.

Please see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617306/c-sharp-constructor-object-parameter-is-passed-by-reference-or-value) for clarity on ref and out parameters.

Best regards,

Comment: That will work, but I don't think it's good design. Why call a constructor *just* to change the value of an out parameter?

Comment: @JonSkeet agreed. Personally I would have a method with a signature such as "Func<string> Service.InitializeCallback()" or "Service.InitializeCallback(out Func<string> callback)" to explictly create the delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You never assign to the factory in the Callee,

Since you are not passing the factory to the service by reference the updates to the variable will not be seen by the caller.

I am uncertain whether or not you can pass parameters to a contructor by reference or not...

Comment: +1 since you are right that adding `ref` modifier would solve the issue

Comment: (Just to explain my edit and deleted comment - I'd misread the answer as saying that it *was* passing by reference.)

Answer (score 0):

To call a `Func<T...>` reference, you just need to call as though it were a normal method. i.e.:

```
class Service
{
    public Service(Func<string> factory)
    {
        string result = factory();
    }
}
```

Note that `Func<string>` will return a `string` type.

**EDIT**

From your comment I have realised what you were *actually* asking in the OP. To be able to assign a value to any parameter, you need to mark it with `out` or `ref`. So your declaration would look like:

```
public Service(out Func<string> factory)
```

or

```
public Service(ref Func<string> factory)
```

Comment: Ok but I want call a factory in the `Caller`, so service just provide some factory to the caller. I can expose a method and use it but this is an other approach I do not want to stick with